# return value debug, VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED

Tags: ansible

I am attempting to parse through the return value but ansible is acting like the long JSON doesn't exist. I know there are similar problems like this but everything I have tried dosn't seem to work.

```yaml
- name:
  community.vmware.vmware_host_config_info:
    esxi_hostname: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
    hostname: "{{ inventory_hostname }}"
    password: "{{ ansible_password }}"
    username: "{{ ansible_user }}"
    validate_certs: no
  register: config_info
  delegate_to: localhost
- debug:
    var: config_info
```

I have tried

- `config_info.host_info[0]`
- `config_info.host_info[localhost.localdomain]`
- `config_info.host_info.localhost.localdomain`

No matter what I attempt, the best I can do is get a

> VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED

I am trying to get the value of the fields i.e `config_info.host_info[0].BufferCache.FlushInterval` is what I would expect it to be.

```json
{
  "changed": false,
  "hosts_info": {
    "localhost.localdomain": {
      "Annotations.WelcomeMessage": "",
      "BufferCache.FlushInterval": 30000,
      "BufferCache.HardMaxDirty": 95
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the [bracket notation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#referencing-key-value-dictionary-variables)

```yaml
bc_fi: "{{ config_info.hosts_info['localhost.localdomain']['BufferCache.FlushInterval'] }}"
```

gives

```yaml
bc_fi: '30000'
```

Comment: Thank you, that did it. It seems that I was to hesitant and didn't go far enough into the dict when I tried it.